# Tortoise SVN Context Menu Issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an issue with Tortise SVN. It has to do with Tortise options not available on my context menu for some files.
This issue started happening when I upgraded from version 1.6 to 1.8 of tortoise. Since then I was unable to create another repository anywhere else on my machine. 
OS Windows 7 64 bit.

I have tried reinstalling and repairing -it has not worked
I do not have any issues with permissions in Registry.

I will leave an image of what I can see, from two different files on my D drive.[image]

Comment: That's been configurable since I can remember. What do you have at "Settings/ General/ Context menu"?

Comment: I have a few Items checked.however I still dont have any options available on the other folder.

Comment: A few items checked? Such as "hide menu for unversioned paths"?

Comment: ummmm....Ok that was it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether to display the context menu on unversioned folders has been configurable since I use TortoiseSVN. You can find the setting at "Settings/ General/ Context menu":

[image: Hide menus for unversioned paths]

There's also an additional preference to blacklist certain paths.